# Count (*) from different tables on condition - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

[image]

In above image, I wish to be listed only the PROUDCT_ID and count from both tables whose count is mismatching. In this case my output should only be:

```
PROUDCT_ID  COUNT  PROUDCT_ID COUNT
1AHO         1     1AHO       2
```

Here, am not interested in comparing values and rather count for proudct_id matters.

Excuse am a beginner to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you want the same information from both tables you can use following

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TableA (PRoDUKT_ID varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TableA VALUES ("1AHO"),("1ADS"),("1ADS")
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TableB (ProDUKT_ID varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TableB VALUES ("1AHO"),("1AHO"),("1ADS"),("1ADS")
> ```

> ```
> SELECT a.ProDUKT_ID, CountA, b.ProDUKT_ID,CountB
> FROM
> (SELECT ProDUKT_ID,COUNT(*) CountA FROM TableA WHERe PRoDUKT_ID = "1AHO") a INNER JOIN
> (SELECT ProDUKT_ID,COUNT(*) CountB FROM TableB WHERe PRoDUKT_ID = "1AHO") b USING (ProDUKT_ID)
> ```
>
> ```
> ProDUKT_ID | CountA | ProDUKT_ID | CountB
> :--------- | -----: | :--------- | -----:
> 1AHO       |      1 | 1AHO       |      2
> ```

> ```
> SELECT a.ProDUKT_ID, CountA, b.ProDUKT_ID,CountB
> FROM
> (SELECT ProDUKT_ID,COUNT(*) CountA FROM TableA GROUP BY ProDUKT_ID) a INNER JOIN
> (SELECT ProDUKT_ID,COUNT(*) CountB FROM TableB GROUP BY ProDUKT_ID) b USING (ProDUKT_ID)
> ```
>
> ```
> ProDUKT_ID | CountA | ProDUKT_ID | CountB
> :--------- | -----: | :--------- | -----:
> 1ADS       |      2 | 1ADS       |      2
> 1AHO       |      1 | 1AHO       |      2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0c849c18e55d2011762ed2d330fa4b7c)*

Comment: If don't want to hard code the "1AHO" PRODUCT_ID



`SELECT t1.PRODUCT_ID, t1.COUNT1, t2.PRODUCT_ID, t2.COUNT2
FROM 
(SELECT t1.PRODUCT_ID, COUNT(t1.price) AS COUNT1
FROM tab1 t1
GROUP BY t1.PRODUCT_ID) t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT t2.PRODUCT_ID, COUNT(t2.price) AS COUNT2
FROM tab2 t2
GROUP BY t2.PRODUCT_ID) t2 ON t1.PRODUCT_ID = t2.PRODUCT_ID 
AND t1.COUNT1 <> t2.COUNT2`

Comment: But it helped you so, good

Comment: @Poonam Kumari - Thanks it worked well..